# Proper way to customize Spark ML estimator (e.g. GaussianMixture) by modified its private method?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, extends, apache-spark-ml

My code use [apache.ml.clustering.GaussianMixture](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/clustering/GaussianMixture.scala), but its init method `private def initRandom(...)` does not work well, so I want to customize a new `init` method.

At first I want to "extends" `class GuassianMixture`, but `initRandom` is a private method.

Then I tried another way, it is to set initial GMM, but sadly source code says that *TODO: SPARK-15785 Support users supplied initial GMM*.

I've also tried to copy the code of `class GuassianMixture` for my custom class, but there are too many things attached to it. [GaussianMixture.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/clustering/GaussianMixture.scala) comes with sort of classes and traits, some of which are only accessible within ML packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by myself. Here is my solution.

I created class `CustomGaussianMixture` which extends `GaussianMixture` from official package `org.apache.spark.ml.clustering`.

And within my project, I created a new package, also named as `org.apache.spark.ml.clustering`(to prevent deal with scope of sort of complexity classes/traits/objects in `org.apache.spark.ml.clustering`). And place my custom class in it.

The next thing is to override the method(`fit`) call `initRandom`, a non-private method, so I can override it. Specifically, Just write my new init method in class `CustomGaussianMixture`, and copy method `fit` from official source code in `GaussianMixture.scala` to class `CustomGaussianMixture`, remember to modify code in `CustomGaussianMixture.fit()` to call my custom init method.

At last, just use `CustomGaussianMixture` instead of `GaussianMixture` when needed.